# How do you find out what calls you can do in an api?

Tags: php, api

I am using the ale api for eve online, but I wonder, how do i figure out what calls i can make?

```
$account = $ale->account->Characters(); 
$characterSheet = $ale->char->CharacterSheet();
```

i found out these two from the help and documentation, and used printl to see whats in there and how to use that, but how can i for excample find the skill names?

Is there a document with all the calls you can make?

[ALE](http://code-box.sk/software/ale.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use PHP's reflection class? It should give you an overview of objects and classes, their methods and properties.

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/16/4/0

Answer (score 1):

Point #3 of that site's documentation, http://code-box.sk/software/ale/documentation/10-getting-started.html, says that the class auto-generates objects to match up with EVE's online api, so I'd suggest starting with EVE's own api documentation. This link, http://www.eveonline.com/api/doc/, would seem to be a good candidate, but shows nothing for me - maybe you have to register for an API key/dev access to get the docs.

Comment: yeah, i was on that link, too bad its empty like that :(

Answer (score 0):

Either the authors of ALE provides such a comprehensive document [(they don't seem to from my quick research)](http://code-box.sk/software/ale/documentation.html) or you could just read the code. It's open source after all.

Answer (score 0):

You could look in the source, and check out what member functions are in the file? Hopefully there is some comment on top of each.

You can use anything that's public :)